# State is updated within a nested array inside a firebase document. How do I handle this with redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm building a simple venue review app using react/redux toolkit/firebase.

My Firestore has one collection, `venues` , and each document within this collection is structured as follows:

```
name:'',
photo:'',
reviews: [
  {
    title:'',
    blurb:'',
    reviewId:''
  },
  {...}
]
```

My app has one slice to control all the state related to venues, including the reviews  - **but should reviews have their own slice?**

I'm asking this because my app is displaying glitchy behaving including crashing on page refresh, and not updating the components when new state is added. Is how I'm handling reviews responsible for causing the problems in my app, and if so, how do I handle it?

Currently my venue state is managed as follows:

Venues fetched in **VenueList.js**...

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchVenues());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

...which triggers thunk in **venueSlice.js**

```
export const fetchVenues = createAsyncThunk("venues/fetchVenues", async () => {
    try {
      const venueArray = [];
      const q = query(collection(db, "venues"));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>
        venueArray.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
      );
      return venueArray;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error: ", err);
    }
  });
```

Reviews added in **AddReview.js**

```
    const handleClick =  (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (title && blurb) {
        const reviewId = nanoid()
        const review = { id, title, blurb, reviewId };
        dispatch(postReview(review));
      }
    };
```

...handled with another thunk in **venueSlice.js**

```
  export const postReview = createAsyncThunk("venues/postReview", async (review) => {
      try {
        const venueRef = doc(db,"venues",review.id)
        await updateDoc(venueRef, {
          reviews: arrayUnion({ 
            title:review.title,
            blurb:review.blurb, 
            reviewId:review.reviewId })
        })
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error :', err)
      }
  })
```

**Note**: Reviews posted to firestore without updating redux global state:

```
const venueSlice = createSlice({
  name: "venues",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchVenues.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.venues = action.payload;
    })
  },
});
```

I extract venue state into `Venue.js`. Venue state (containing reviews) is then passed as props to `Reviews.js`, where reviews are added/deleted.

***Venue.js***

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import AddReview from "../../components/AddReview";
import Reviews from "../../components/Reviews";

const Venue = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  
  const venues = useSelector((state) => state.venues);
  console.log(venues)
  const venue = venues.venues.filter((item) => item.id === id);

  console.log(venues)

  const content = venue.map((item) => (
    <div className="venue-page-main" key = {item.name}>
      <h2>{item.name}</h2>
      <img src={item.photo} alt = "venue"/>
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <>
        {content}
        <AddReview id = {id}/>
        <Reviews venue = {venue}/>
    </>
  );
};
 
export default Venue;
```

**Reviews.js**

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { deleteReview,fetchVenues } from "../features/venues/venueSlice";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Reviews = ({venue}) => {

    
    const venueId = venue[0].id


    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const removeReview = (review) => {
        dispatch(deleteReview({...review, id:venueId}))
    }


    const content = venue && venue[0].reviews && venue[0].reviews.map(review => (
        <div className="review" key = {review.reviewId}>
            <h2>{review.title}</h2>
            <h3>{review.blurb}</h3>
            <div>
                <p>Edit</p>
                <button onClick = {() => removeReview(review)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    ))

    return (
        <div className="all-reviews">
            {content}
        </div>
    )
}
 
export default Reviews;
```

Here's the entire **venueSlice.js** file

```
import { createSlice,createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { collection,query,getDocs,doc,updateDoc,arrayUnion, arrayRemove, FieldValue } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../firebaseConfig";

const initialState = {
    venues: []
}

export const fetchVenues = createAsyncThunk("venues/fetchVenues", async () => {
    try {
      const venueArray = [];
      const q = query(collection(db, "venues"));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>
        venueArray.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
      );
      return venueArray;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error: ", err);
    }
  });

  export const postReview = createAsyncThunk("venues/postReview", async (review) => {
      try {
        const venueRef = doc(db,"venues",review.id)
        await updateDoc(venueRef, {
          reviews: arrayUnion({ 
            title:review.title,
            blurb:review.blurb, 
            reviewId:review.reviewId })
        })
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error :', err)
      }
  })

export const deleteReview = createAsyncThunk("venues/deleteReview", async (review) => {

  const newReview = {blurb:review.blurb, title: review.title, reviewId: review.reviewId}

  try {
    const venueRef = doc(db,"venues",review.id)
    await updateDoc(venueRef, {
      reviews: arrayRemove(newReview)
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error: ', err)
  }
})


const venueSlice = createSlice({
  name: "venues",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchVenues.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.venues = action.payload;
    })
  },
});

export default venueSlice.reducer
```